# Fit a logistic regression model separately for each column in r

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, glm

I'm new to r I need to run a loop or use sapply to fit a logistic regression model to each column (beginning with 'rs') separately with the below formula:

AD ~ [cov1:cov6] + rs1 then repeat for each rs2, rs3 etc.

I would also need to repeat the above code but change the formula to:

AD ~ [cov1:cov6] + rs1 * alcohol_intake then also repeat for each rs2, rs3 etc.

example data:

```
set.seed(543)
mydata <- data.frame(ID = 1:100, 
                     sex = sample(1:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE), 
                     age = runif(100, min= 35, max = 70), 
                     bmi = runif(100, min= 15, max = 35),
                     smoker = rep(c('smoker', 'not smoker')),
                     alcohol_intake = rep(c('regular', 'not regular')),
                     AD = sample(0:1, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     cov1 = runif(100, min= 0.0000, max = 1.0000),
                     cov2 = runif(100, min= -3.013e-02, max = 1.818e-02),
                     cov3 = runif(100, min= -3.562e-02, max = 1.540e-02),
                     cov4 = runif(100, min= -2.356e-02, max = 1.685e-02),
                     cov5 = runif(100, min= -1.392e-02, max = 2.894e-02),
                     cov6 = runif(100, min= -1.896e-02, max = 2.136e-02),
                     rs1 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE), 
                     rs2 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs3 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs4 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs5 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs6 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs7 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs8 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs9 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs10 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs11 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs12 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs13 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs14 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs15 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs16 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs17 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs18 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs19 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs20 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs21 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs22 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs23 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs24 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs25 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs26 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs27 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs28 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs29 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs30 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on my comment in my previous answer that I feel conversion to long format would be beneficial in the long run...

Converting to long format is simple:

```
mydataLong <- mydata %>% 
                pivot_longer(
                  cols=starts_with("rs"), 
                  names_to="Variable", 
                  values_to="Value"
                )
```

Which gives a data frame that looks like this (dropping some columns to display the section of the data frame that is of interest):

```
mydataLong %>% select(AD, starts_with("cov"), Variable, Value)
# A tibble: 15,000 × 9
      AD  cov1    cov2    cov3   cov4     cov5    cov6 Variable Value
   <int> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    <int>
 1     0 0.490 -0.0201 -0.0277 0.0142 -0.00377 0.00758 rs1          0
 2     0 0.490 -0.0201 -0.0277 0.0142 -0.00377 0.00758 rs2          0
 3     0 0.490 -0.0201 -0.0277 0.0142 -0.00377 0.00758 rs3          1
 4     0 0.490 -0.0201 -0.0277 0.0142 -0.00377 0.00758 rs4          0
 5     0 0.490 -0.0201 -0.0277 0.0142 -0.00377 0.00758 rs5          2
 6     0 0.490 -0.0201 -0.0277 0.0142 -0.00377 0.00758 rs6          1
 7     0 0.490 -0.0201 -0.0277 0.0142 -0.00377 0.00758 rs7          0
 8     0 0.490 -0.0201 -0.0277 0.0142 -0.00377 0.00758 rs8          0
 9     0 0.490 -0.0201 -0.0277 0.0142 -0.00377 0.00758 rs9          1
10     0 0.490 -0.0201 -0.0277 0.0142 -0.00377 0.00758 rs10         2
```

To exactly reproduce the analysis requested by OP, I can use the tidyverse's `group_map()` function.  `group_map` applies a function to a grouped data frame and returns a list whose elements are the results of applying the function provided to each group of the data frame in turn.  The function should have two arguments, conventionally named `.x` and `.y`.  `.x` contains the data in the current group.  `.y` contains a single row and only those columns that define the current group.

```
resultList <- mydataLong %>%
                group_by(Variable) %>% 
                group_map(
                function(.x, .y) {
                  glm(
                    AD ~ cov1 + cov2 + cov3 + cov4 +cov5 + cov6 + Value, 
                    data=.x, 
                    family="binomial"
                  )
                }
              )
resultList[[17]]
Call:  glm(formula = AD ~ cov1 + cov2 + cov3 + cov4 + cov5 + cov6 + 
    Value, family = "binomial", data = .x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         cov1         cov2         cov3         cov4         cov5         cov6        Value  
     0.1370       0.0422       3.9611       1.0340     -10.2308       3.5968       3.1808      -0.1629  

Degrees of Freedom: 499 Total (i.e. Null);  492 Residual
Null Deviance:      693.1 
Residual Deviance: 688.5    AIC: 704.5
```

The advantage of this approach is that it is robust.  Once the data frame is in long format, the same code will work correctly for any number of response variables, and regardless of what for their names take.  That's not true of the "wide format" solution.  For example, OP pointed out that in their real use case, response variables had names that look like `rs65387690_A` rather than `rs1`.  That required a change to the code.  That's not necessary here: a source of error has been removed and the maintenance of production code has been reduced.

I think it's also worth mentioning the `broom` package here.  `broom` attempts to remove inconsistency in the format of objects returned by various analysis functions: it converts the object returned to a data frame and attempts into standardise column names.  Essentially, it does this by defining a generic function `tidy()`.  If `broom` doesn't provide a `tidy()` method for your particular flavour of results object, it's pretty easy to write your own.

So, adapting my solution to use `broom` and adding a call to `bind_rows()` to the end of the pipe, I get

```
library(broom)

mydataLong %>% 
 group_by(Variable) %>% 
 group_map(
   function(.x, .y) {
     glm(
       AD ~ cov1 + cov2 + cov3 + cov4 +cov5 + cov6 + Value, 
       data=.x, 
       family="binomial"
     ) %>% 
     tidy() %>% 
       add_column(Variable=.y$Variable, .before=1)
   }
) %>% 
bind_rows()
# A tibble: 240 × 6
   Variable term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
   <chr>    <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 rs1      (Intercept)  -0.308      0.245   -1.26    0.209 
 2 rs1      cov1          0.0277     0.354    0.0784  0.938 
 3 rs1      cov2          3.67       6.79     0.540   0.589 
 4 rs1      cov3          0.362      6.01     0.0602  0.952 
 5 rs1      cov4         -8.92       8.09    -1.10    0.270 
 6 rs1      cov5          4.48       7.11     0.630   0.529 
 7 rs1      cov6          2.27       8.06     0.282   0.778 
 8 rs1      Value         0.263      0.114    2.30    0.0214
 9 rs10     (Intercept)  -0.0858     0.248   -0.346   0.729 
10 rs10     cov1          0.0583     0.352    0.166   0.869 
# … with 230 more rows
```

So the results of all the analyses are in a single data frame, which I find much easier to handle downstream than a list of individual objects.

`broom::tidy()` can be used in the "wide format" solution as well as this "long-format" variation.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, that works well on my data. Would the long format then allow me to add AD ~ cov1 + cov2 + cov3 + cov4 +cov5 + cov6 + Value * past_smoker to the formula? Past_smoker is a column of factors "past smoker" "not past smoker".

Comment: Yes. Just modify the formula to fit the model you want. You could even make the formula a parameter to the function called by `group_map()`. See the online doc for how to do it. It follows the same form as with `lapply` but it may not be intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "[cov1:cov6]".  I assume you mean each covariate from `cov1` to `cov6`.

Given the form of your data frame, I would do what you want something like this.  The key is to know that `as.formula()` will convert a string to a formula, so you can use `paste0()` to construct the necessary formulae on the fly.

```
resultList <- lapply(
  1:30,
  function(x) {
    glm(
     as.formula(paste0("AD ~ cov1 + cov2 + cov3 + cov4 +cov5 + cov6 + rs", x)), 
     data=mydata, 
     family="binomial"
    )    
  }
)
```

`resultList` is a list of 30 elements.  The xxxxth element of which is the result of fitting a model involving `rsxxxx`.  For example:

```
resultList[[10]]

Call:  glm(formula = as.formula(paste0("AD ~ cov1 + cov2 + cov3 + cov4 +cov5 + cov6 + rs", 
    x)), family = "binomial", data = mydata)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         cov1         cov2         cov3         cov4         cov5         cov6         rs10  
     0.1876      -0.2297      -2.8596      -5.3283      -1.2817       1.2763      18.5162      -0.1520  

Degrees of Freedom: 499 Total (i.e. Null);  492 Residual
Null Deviance:      693.1 
Residual Deviance: 683.9    AIC: 699.9
```

I'll leave it to you to work out what you need to do for your interaction models.

As an aside, I would also investigate turning your data into long format and then using the tidyverse's `group_by()` and `group_map()` functions.  Personally, I find this approach far easier, more robust, more efficient and easier to maintain and document than the `lapply` approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Limey, sorry I should have specified but the names for my 'rs' columns in my actual data are actually like this rs65387690_A. If I was to turn the data into long format how could I do that to run the logistic regression model?

Comment: I'll answer your "long format" query tomorrow.  To deal with the "awkward" rs names, collect the names in a vector and then use that vector as the first argument of `lapply`, making the corresponding change to the `paste0()` call.

Comment: great thanks that worked - I await your response tomorrow.