# How to lump models into a list in R

Tags: r

I am not sure that "list" is the right word, but I knew how to do this but lost the code.
I have multiple models I would like to illustrate with stargazer. Instead of typing every single model, I would like to put them into a list that I can then Stargazer and be done with it. Right now I have:

```
model1 <- lm(Dependent ~ Variable1 + Variable2 + Variable3, Variable4, data = dataset)
model2 <- lm(Dependent ~ Variable5 + Variable2 + Variable3, Variable4, data = dataset)
model3 <- lm(Dependent ~ Variable6 + Variable2 + Variable3, Variable4, data = dataset)
model4 <- lm(Dependent ~ Variable7 + Variable2 + Variable3, Variable4, data = dataset)
model5 <- lm(Dependent ~ Variable8 + Variable2 + Variable3, Variable4, data = dataset)
```

I would like to put all these models into a "list", let's say, "List1" so that I can then do `Stargazer(List1)` and visualize these.

*Edited a mistake in the formula that had a comma instead of a plus sign -- but this was not part of the question. Just edited for clarity.

Comment: You can't use `,` in a model formula. I assume your first formula should be `Dependent ~ Variable1 + Variable2 + Variable3 + Variable4`, and similarly for the rest?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fit a logistic regression model separately for each column in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73294852/fit-a-logistic-regression-model-separately-for-each-column-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the answer. For anyone who is lurking, this is how you lump multiple models under a list to then illustrate with Stargazer or something else:

```
name_of_your_choice <- list(model1, model2, model3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to work with strings than formula objects, so I tend to build strings for my model formulas and then use `as.formula` to turn them into formula objects for modeling.

In your case, something like this:

```
first_var = paste0("Variable", c(1, 5, 6, 7, 8))
formulas = sprintf("Dependent ~ %s + Variable2 + Variable3 + Variable4", first_var)
models = list()
for(i in seq_along(formulas)) {
  models[[first_var[i]]] = lm(as.formula(formulas[i]), data = dataset)
}
```

This will create a list `models` with names `Variable1, Variabl5, ...` containing model objects with corresponding formulas.